# Reusing Mule connectors and validation flows

Tags: maven, mule

How to reuse mule code (flows, exception strategies, database connectors, validators) across several projects. It's a application specific reusable artifacts, not an enterprise wide reuse.

For ex: I have some master code( validators, flows, and exception stratagies) which should be reused in a 15 different flows. (i.e 15 different mule projects). We are not using maven at the moment. One way I explored is, we could jar it and publish to local nexus repo, and re-use it via pom. Is there any other way ?

If possible, I also would like to make it dynamic, such that if I change the master code and deploy, it should be in effect without having to redeploy the ones that are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse flows etc. (everything which is in Mule xml files) and Java classes by placing them in a plain Java project, building a jar from it and placing the jar on the classpaths of the importing Mule projects.

To use the stuff in the xml files, import them with .

Your question sounds like you already know this part.

I recommend building all Mule projects and the so called master project with Maven, Mule projects with packaging Mule, the master project with packaging jar.

Maven will pack the master part inside the using projects, so there is no dynamic update.

When you want this dynamic update, don't build with Maven or set the scope to "provided". In this case the master is not packaged in the other Mule projects. You have to make sure it is on the server classpath, e.g. in lib/user. Then you can change it there, restart the Mule server and all projects get the update.

Same with another level of indirection/possibility for grouping can be done with Mule domains.

All the dynamic stuff described so far does only for on premise Mule servers, not for CloudHub.